# PFsense stability with IPv6

Tags: ipv6, pfsense, vyatta

We are considering getting a 1Gig rack from a DC and as a little bonus they throw in a /48 v6 for you. I figure this can be split so that each client has their own /64 to use as they please... The real question being has anyone used IPv6 with PFsense; I know it can be hacked it but is it stable or is it better to choose Vyatta instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there's no IPv6 support within PFSense.

It was slated for "after" the 2.0 release, but I've been waiting for 2.0 to come out of beta for 18 months now, and I'm not holding my breath.

You can track PFSense's [progress on IPv6 integration here](http://redmine.pfsense.org/issues/show/177). It turns out there's a [hacked workaround here](http://remcobressers.nl/2009/08/configuring-native-ipv6-pfsense/) (the one you referred to), but it's... less than ideal.

Comment: Pretty much what mark said -- Ain't gonna happen (soon) in the GUI, but works fine from the command line.  If you really *need* IPv6 I'd roll a FreeBSD or OpenBSD firewall and just work from the CLI if you feel comfortable in that environment...

Comment: Well being that stability is important Vyatta might be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

IPv6 is *the* thing that made me go from pfsense to vyatta.

Tired of waiting for pfsense2.0+, tired of ugly hacks that breaks the system uniformity (no proper GUI, packages only working w/ ipv4...)

As I'm more of a GNU/Linux guy, I feel a lot more comfortable with Vyatta, and its ipv6 support has proven to be very resilient.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to have ipv6 support, use [Monowall](http://m0n0.ch)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the IPv6 board on the forum, a number of things done already, a custom git branch you can sync to, and much more info there.
http://forum.pfsense.org/index.php/board,52.0.html

Comment: I choose mark's answer because it related to stability not just possibility.